# What is the best, average and worst case for this specific implementation of Quick Sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm aware that the best and average time is O(n log(n)), and the worst time is O(n^2). Can anyone tell me when these cases actually occur in this particular implementation? How does it vary across other implementations?

```
    private void quickSort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;
        // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
        int pivot = array[low + (high - low) / 2];

        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {
            // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the left list
            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the right list
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
            // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
            // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
            // values.
            // As we are done we can increase i and j
            if (i <= j) {
                swap(array, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // Recursion
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(low, j);
        if (i < high)
            quickSort(i, high);
    }
```

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a close look at pivot selection.

Comment: What happens if all the numbers have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

The worst case happens when you chose a pivot such that, after the "Divide into two lists" part, ends up at one extreme of the array (far left or far right). The reason is: one of the two recursive calls will do *almost no work*, while the other will do almost *all of the work again*.

For example: you have a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 100 and you choose a pivot in the middle. Say the pivot is 1. You run the "Divide into two lists" part and now you have to sort 0 elements on the left and 99 elements on the right.

---

The best case happens when the pivot splits in half the two lists (in the permutation example, when you choose a pivot that is around 50).